# RequestBody JSON format has single quotes

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I have a controller class in my SpringBoot app.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/{database}/alerts")
public class ControllerB {
  @Autowired private ServiceB serviceB;

  @Autowired
  private B b;

  @Autowired
  ControllerB(B b,ServiceB serviceB){
      this.b = b;
      this.serviceB = serviceB;
  }

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public B dosomethingCrazy(@RequestBody BImpl bimpl)  {


      String response = serviceB.dosomethingImportant();
      return bimpl;

  }

}
```

The problem arises when the requestBody has a single quote in the value. For example if the requestbody is {"name" : "peter o'toole"}, it throws a http 400

> "status":400,"error":"Bad Request","exception":"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException","message":"JSON parse error: Unexpected end-of-input in VALUE_STRING

Any idea how Jackson can map a single quote value to the object field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create this class to setup the Jackson and enable Single quotes:

```
@Configuration
public class JsonConfigurer {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = builder.build();
        objectMapper.enable(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_SINGLE_QUOTES)
        return objectMapper;
    }

}
```

Comment: Dherik, Thanks! but how do i apply the class? I am a newbie in Spring, so sorry if this is a basic question.

Comment: Just create this class inside some package that Spring can scan. Just try :). Will work even in the same package of your controller

Comment: Thank you!! The other answer by Wim Deblauwe works too.

Answer (score 8):

Set the following property in your `application.properties` file:

```
spring.jackson.parser.allow-single-quotes=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what version of Spring Boot you are using. With 1.4.3.RELEASE, I can curl just fine like this to my endpoint:

```
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: */*" -d "{\"name\":\"peter o'toole\"}" "https://localhost:5443/test"
```

I should add though that our Jackson version is 2.7.2. I am not sure if that causes it to work.