# how to return custom response from rest webservice spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I am expecting output **exactly** like below(you see single quotes)

```
{
    "success": true,
    "friends":  ['Kanchhi@example.com','modi@example.com','maya@example.com','jetli@example.com','john@example.com'] ,
    "count": 5
}
```

but presently i am getting like this:(we have to remove double quotes from this)

```
{
    "success": true,
    "friends": "['Kanchhi@example.com','modi@example.com','maya@example.com','jetli@example.com','john@example.com']",
    "count": 5
}
```

Rest method

```
@PostMapping(path = "/my", consumes = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Map> getFriendListByEmail(@Valid @RequestBody String value) { 
                LinkedHashMap<Object, Object> map23 = new LinkedHashMap<>(); 
                myList=userService.getfriendList(value); //getting some list say we have got 5 list of emails
                String s  ="'"+myList.toString().replace("[","").replace("]", "").replace(" ","").replace(",","','")+"'"; 
                map23.put("success", true);
                map23.put("friends", "["+s+"]"); // trying to put the updated string 
                map23.put("count", myList.size());  
                return new ResponseEntity<Map>(map23, HttpStatus.OK);  
    }
```

Comment: So instead of putting the actual list in the map, you put in a string representation of it... and you're surprised you received a string representation in the output JSON?

Comment: EDIT: Ah I just noticed your requirement for single quoted strings

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49159300/requestbody-json-format-has-single-quotes)

Comment: @HadiJ But I want to apply single quotes only to one endpoint (only to one method), i don't want to globally make single quotes! Any other solution!

Comment: maybe you can by defining separate `object mapper` just for this service resolve this issue

Comment: @HadiJ The link you have shared is a solution of different stuffs ! i tried this but this did not get output as i am expecting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Alessandro Power's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54152757/6413377) is absolutely correct you might have no option.

It is clear that the required response is not valid JSON but the trick is to return a string. So construct and return a string instead of `ResponseEntity`. Declare your method like:

```
public String getFriendListByEmail(...)
```

In its body do not use `Map` but something like this:

```
String s = "{\"success\": true, ";
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
s += "\"friends\": " + om.writeValueAsString(myList).replace('"', '\'') + ", ";
s += "\"count\": " + myList.size();
s += "}";
return s;
```

Answer (score 4):

To those suggesting he just place the actual list in the map: the question requires that the output of the list have single quoted strings.

But single quoted strings are not allowed by the JSON standard. If you *really* want to do this you'd probably have to hack a solution that avoids the JSON serialization and manually writes your entire pseudo-JSON response to the response body. This, of course, is a terrible idea; instead you should revisit your requirement to have single quoted strings.

Comment: If you really want to go down this path: you can pass in an `OutputStream` object as a parameter and write the response body yourself. You won't benefit from any automatic JSON serialization though.

Comment: how to do this! any example please

Comment: Do you even try to Google `OutputStream`?

Comment: I am first time hearing it. As i said you earlier, i am new newbie

Comment: ...hence why you Google the terms you're unfamiliar with

Comment: Did you mean like this https://dzone.com/articles/jax-rs-streaming-response